# Bourne shell scripting reading file

Tags: shell, unix, sh

This simple program supposed to read the file lines, but instead it outputs "cat" every time. What is the problem?

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
  echo $line
done <file
```

**Edit:**

`file` is supposed to be the users input file when calling the program from the terminal. Like:

```
./programname file
```

Comment: What do you means it "outputs cat"? As it it prints the word "cat" or it just shows all the liens?

Comment: @kamillaKan What is the content of `file`? Update the question with the same

Comment: @Zephyr Pellerin it just prints the word cat

Comment: @sjsam this is suppose to be the users input file when calling the program from the terminal. Like: ./programname file

Answer (score 3):

> this is suppose to be the users input file when calling the program
>   from the terminal. Like: ./programname file

In this case you should be doing

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f "$1" ] # checking if file exist
then 
 while read line
 do
   echo "$line"
 done <"$1" # double quotes important to prevent word splitting
else
  echo "Sorry file $1 doesn't exist"
fi
```

Here `$1` represents the first parameter that you pass to the script.

**Interesting reads:**

1. What is [[ word splitting ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) ?
2. Shell script [[ parameters ]](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters/)

Comment: Your code runs fine for me and seems as close to an answer as the OP is going to get unless he provides more info.  So: +1.

Comment: @John1024 : Thanks pal. I'm more concerned about the downvote here. Unless the downvoters provide me some information, they are depriving me of a great learning opportunity. I am  taking this to International Court of Justice, ie the meta ;)

Comment: Sometimes you never know. Those with the integrity will backup their downvote with a comment, those that lack integrity won't. The community can tell the difference between the two quite easily. It's as simple as that. Don't sweat it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin :  `Those with the integrity will backup..` Agree with you 100%. :-)